# Php Curl :on timeout, close connection but not return any content

Tags: php, php-curl

When I run curl to a server and also set a timeout, the server cannot transfer all the content set by the "Content-Length" header. the problem is that the connection falls due to timeout and no output remains.
Is there an operator in the options that allows to transfer the content to the output even if the connection times out?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>1800,
));
$data= curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $data;
?>

* About to connect() to 2.100.x.x port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2.100.x.x... * connected
* Connected to 2.100.x.x (2.100.x.x) port 80 (#0)
> GET /example.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 2.100.x.x
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2019 21:00:36 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 16781312
< Cache-Control: private
< Connection: close
<
* Operation timed out after 1800000 milliseconds with 4598060 out of 16781312 bytes received
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: "transfer the content to the output" ...what content, to what output? Are you talking about the `echo $data` line? Clearly if the cURL request times out there will be no response from the remote server, so nothing to display. You can't magic a response from nowhere. You could display your own error message though

Comment: Having said that, if you're having problems with timeouts, have you considered increasing the length of the timeout value?

Comment: Maybe you should not set a timeout, but set CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT instead.

Answer (score 0):

the content it's binary transfer.. but it's like a streaming content.
for example without CURLOPT_TIMEOUT curl go in infinite and the connection won't stop, but the problem if activate timeout the connection terminate but not trasfer the output readed.
if i used file_get_contents, on timeout i have the output with or without timeout setup.
why need use curl instead of file_get_contents ? because i need to setup curl with multi curl. with file_get_contents i can't make a multi call without waiting.